# How to trigger KDB from kernel code?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a kernel with KDB compiled in. I can trigger it using `/proc/sysrq-trigger` and all, but I would like to be able to enter KDB explicitly from the kernel code without having to ressort to a kernel panic which will mess my system up. Something like:

```
if (interesting_condition)
    enter_kdb();
```

Is there a similar function in the kernel or a better way to trigger KDB from it than doing a page fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KDB_ENTER()`
As simple as that.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to exist in the latest kernel source. git grep KDB_ENTER does not return anything meaningful.

Comment: It should be in the platform dependent headers (`/include/asm-xxx/kdb.h`). I don't know about git, but lxr.linux.no doesn't show these headers. In my Linux 2.6, it exists in both i386 and x86_64.

Comment: Still no go. I am compiling for ARM though, with a 2.6.39 kernel. However I have found out that `kgdb_breakpoint` does the trick.